# Stored Procedure results in Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012, openrowset

I have a requirement to provide the results of my analysis in different sheets under one excel file. Currently i'm manually copying and pasting the results into excel (10 sheets). How I can use the stored procedure to automate this?

I have tried something like below.

```
insert into OPENROWSET(
   'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
   'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\Results\test.xls;;HDR=YES', 
   'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
select * from MY_TABLE WHERE ATTR='YES'

insert into OPENROWSET(
   'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
   'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\Results\test.xls;;HDR=YES', 
   'SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$]')
select * from MY_TABLE WHERE ATTR='No'
```

It is giving me error

> SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries'

I will try to get the access from admin.Hopefully after that it will work?
But Is there any other way of doing this? Also I want to know how to do this inside a procedure for providing the results in different sheets.

Comment: Consider a client coding solution that connects to your database and reads query results into sheets. See ADO for Excel VBA.

Comment: In the excel file, choose the option Data from SQL Server, then your query will have to be like this (this is one I used before), but the column names, etc. needs to match exactly what your SP spits out: `select * from openrowset
 (
 'sqlncli'
, 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;'
, 'exec [yourcompanyname].dbo.kv_sp_getWhseQtys_AW ''2019-08-12''

 with result sets

(
  (
    ItemCode varchar(50)
,   ItemDescription varchar(200)
,   ItemGroup varchar(50)
,   AvgUnitCost float
,   LatestUCst float
  )
)'
 )`

Comment: Provide me with the column names and their data type of the results from your Stored Procedure, then I'll provide a proper answer to your question @Avinash...

Comment: I was able to solve this by creating `Sequence Container` in `SSIS` package. Thanks all for the inputs

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
GO
```